# Mouse Flicker on Triple Monitor setup Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ati, multiple-monitors, mouse, display, flicker

I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04 with Kernel version 3.13. I have two ATI HD4650 graphics cards and am attempting to push display on 3 monitors. The first card is attached to 2 monitors via an HDMI and DVI connection. The second card is attached to 1 monitor via an HDMI connection.

Everything works perfectly except for the mouse flicker I am having. This mouse flicker only occurs when I have the display attached to the second card enabled. When the mouse is inside the second card's display (left-most monitor) the mouse is steady. However, when the mouse moves into either of the 2 displays on the right, the mouse starts doing a random flicker.

I do not have any proprietary drivers installed at this time. The 4000 series cards are now only supported by a legacy AMD driver which only works up to kernel version 3.4. I am aware of a unofficial legacy driver but I have not had time to mess with it yet.

Any ideas to eliminate this mouse flickering would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Install this PPA, it will add the patch to Compiz to fix the screen refresh issue often seen on ATI based graphics.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:townsend/compiz-nvidia-refresh-test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

[Source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1278223)